# cannot install windows XP after deleting Ubuntu 16.04 and formating all the hard drive?

Tags: grub2

when I put the usb drive that contain XP files it appears to me a black window with this

```
                 gnu grub version 2.02 beta2-36 ubuntu 3.12 

minimal BASH- like line editing is supported for the first word, tab lists possible
command completion. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions

grub>
```

Note:I am new with linux!

Comment: in order to make a bootable win xp install media, try yumi (under windows) https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/

Comment: Restart the PC, press the button that opens the BIOS settings, go to boot section and put the USB drive in the top of boot list, then save and exit. After restarting this time, it should boot on the USB drive.

Comment: Just an FYI, if you are installing Windows XP, you've opened yourself to a can of worms.  Microsoft no longer supports Windows XP, and running it opens you to a whole host of attack vectors and incompatibilities with the rest of the world's software (i.e. not much supports XP anymore)

Answer (score 1):

Files aren't enough to create a bootable USB device. When you put Linux or any other OS onto a USB disk for installation, you are really putting three things onto the disk. The three parts are the MBR (master boot record), the first thing your computer reads and executes when you boot the USB device, the file system (where the files are stored, written, and read), and the files to install the OS (i386, docs, etc. for XP). Don't just copy the files over to the USB. Use Rufus ~ https://rufus.akeo.ie/ to create bootable USB drives.

Answer (score 0):

This black screen appears because you deleted Ubuntu without deleting grub, so when you restart your PC, it hangs on grub since there is no Operating System (OS) to start.
**To fix this :**
First, you should use a tool or a software to make a USB drive bootable (I suggest [Universal USB installer](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) if you are running on Windows or GParted if you are using Linux).
Then, plug your USB drive to the PC and restart it. Then, before the grub appears, press the button that opens the **BIOS** settings. After that, go to **boot** section and put the **USB drive** in the *top* of boot list. Then, save and exit.
After restarting this time, it should boot on the USB drive and you can install Windows XP on your PC.